# Errors are not displayed when parsing several statements with FParsec

Tags: f#, parsec, fparsec

I have a statement parser, when I run the program with this one as a parser argument, all the errors are displayed. To be able to parse several statements, I have defined a new parser; however, when there are errors, it does not display them.

Here is this parser:

```
(* -------- Program -------- *)

let pprog, pprogimpl = createParserForwardedToRef ()
pprogimpl := attempt (many pstatement |>> Program)
```

`pstatement` defining all possible statements via another parser.

I would like to know why errors are not displayed with the `pprog` parser. Did I make a mistake? Forget something?

**Edit**

I was finally able to solve the error by changing the `many' instruction, and replacing it with`manyTill`. Apparently, the problem came from the fact that he couldn't handle the "listed" errors, if you know more anyway, I'd be curious to know.

```
let pprog, pprogimpl = createParserForwardedToRef ()
pprogimpl := (attempt (manyTill (pstatement) eof) |>> Program)
```

Comment: Any specific reason you need `attempt` around your `many pstatement |>> Program`? What happens if you remove it? Because I wonder if `attempt` is suppressing the error message(s).

Comment: `attempt` or not that doesn't change anything, it still doesn't display anything.

Comment: @Foxy The chance that you get a helpful answer is much higher if you post a self-contained example demonstrating the issue (i.e. a minimal complete grammar and example input).

Comment: I finally found a solution, see **edit**.